# canvas - cant see color of my stars

Tags: javascript, canvas

i create canvas animated background... but... i cant see my stars...
Stars should be white.

code:

```
window.onload = sky();
        function sky(){
            var canvas = document.getElementById("sky");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

            var W = window.innerWidth;
            var H = window.innerHeight;
            canvas.width = W;
            canvas.height = H;

            var ms = 100;
            var stars =[];

            for (var i=0; i<ms; i++){
                stars.push({
                    x: Math.random()*W,
                    y: Math.random()*H,
                    r: Math.random()*5+2,
                    d: Math.random()+1
                })
            }
            function drawStars(){
                ctx.clearRect(0,0,W,H);
                ctx.fillStyle = "white";
                ctx.beginPath();
                for(var i=0; i<ms; i++){
                    var s = stars[i];
                    ctx.moveTo(s.x, s.y);
                    ctx.arc(s.x, s.y, 0, Math.Pi*2, true);
                }
                ctx.fill();
                moveStars();
            }
            var angle = 0;
            function moveStars(){
                angle +=0.01;
                for( var i=0; i<ms; i++){
                    var s = stars[i];
                    s.y += Math.pow(s.d, 2)+1;
                    s.x += Math.sin(angle)*2;

                    if(s.y>H){
                        stars[i] = {x: Math.random()+W, y:0, r: s.r, d: s.d};
                    }
                }
            }
            setInterval(drawStars,25);
        }
```

my background color is black, so i should see white stars...
fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w39fs7at/

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the radius argument to the arc function. Also Math.Pi is undefined, it should be Math.PI.

So, change `ctx.arc(s.x, s.y, 0, Math.Pi*2, true);` to

```
ctx.arc(s.x, s.y, 5, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
```

Where 5 is the radius of the star.

Answer (score 0):

Things to look at:

```
window.onload=sky();
```

should be

```
window.onload=sky;
```

to set the load event handler to the `sky` function, not the return value of calling it.

```
ctx.clearRect(0,0,W,H);
```

sets canvas pixels to transparent black which lets the background show through. If the background is white....

```
ctx.fillStyle= "black";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,W,H);
```

sets the canvas pixels to solid black which obscures the  background color.

In the call to the context's `arc` method, the radius parameter is missing and `Math.Pi` is a typo for `Math.PI`.
For a fix try

```
ctx.arc(s.x, s.y, s.r, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
```

That leaves `moveStars`. I didn't work out what it is supposed to do. As coded it moves the stars off screen, but  they come back after a while (you have to wait) as a wave of falling stars:.

```js
    "use strict";
    window.onload = sky;
    
    function sky(){
        var canvas = document.getElementById("sky");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    
        var W = window.innerWidth;
        var H = window.innerHeight;
        canvas.width = W;
        canvas.height = H;
    
        var ms = 100;
        var stars =[];
    
        for (var i=0; i<ms; i++){
            stars.push({
                x: Math.random()*W,
                y: Math.random()*H,
                r: Math.random()*2+5,
                d: Math.random()+1
            })
        }
        function drawStars(){
            ctx.fillStyle="black";
            ctx.fillRect(0,0,W,H);
            ctx.fillStyle = "white";
            ctx.beginPath();
            for(var i=0; i<ms; i++){
                var s = stars[i];
                ctx.moveTo(s.x, s.y);
                ctx.arc(s.x, s.y, s.r, 0, Math.PI*2, true); 
            }
            ctx.fill();
            moveStars();
        }
        var angle = 0;
        function moveStars(){
            angle +=0.01;
            for( var i=0; i<ms; i++){
                var s = stars[i];
                s.y += Math.pow(s.d, 2)+1;
                s.x += Math.sin(angle)*2;
    
                if(s.y>H){
                    stars[i] = {x: Math.random()+W, y:0, r: s.r, d: s.d};
                }
            }
        }
    
        setInterval(drawStars,25);
    }
```

```html
<canvas id="sky"></canvas>
```

Hope it helps!